# Grizzly server exception

Tags: java, gradle, ubuntu-14.04, grizzly

I've created a REST server using JAX-RS. I use gradle to build the project and deploy Grizzly server.
When I run `gradle server` to build the server, it throws a exception:

```
:server
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainerProvider.createContainer(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Application;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerFactory.createContainer(ContainerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.java:110)
    at toDo_REST.Server.main(Server.java:40)
:server FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':server'.
> Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I've gradle 2.1. My java version is 1.8.0_25. I run it on Ubuntu 14.04 x64.

[My full project here](https://github.com/javiertello/Lab2/tree/master/ToDo_REST)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo in the build.gradle:

```
diff --git a/ToDo_REST/build.gradle b/ToDo_REST/build.gradle
index 42da619..b3fbcc7 100644
--- a/ToDo_REST/build.gradle
+++ b/ToDo_REST/build.gradle
@@ -7,7 +7,7 @@
 }

 dependencies {
-   compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-grizzly2-http:2.3.1'
+   compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-grizzly2-http:2.13'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:2.13'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:2.13'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-moxy:2.13'
```